# Accessing private fields in the base and child classes using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a simple program:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PlayWithReflection
{
class MyDisposable:IDisposable
{
    private  string _name;

    public MyDisposable(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_name + " is disposed");
    }
}

class MyBaseClass : IDisposable
{
    protected MyDisposable _baseProtectedDisposableA = new MyDisposable("_baseProtectedDisposableA");
    private MyDisposable _baseDisposableB = new MyDisposable("_baseDisposableB");

    public MyDisposable BaseProtectedDisposableA
    {
        get { return _baseProtectedDisposableA; }
    }

    public MyDisposable BaseDisposableB
    {
        get { return _baseDisposableB; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var fieldInfos = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
        {
            var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
            if (value is IDisposable)
            {
                ((IDisposable)value).Dispose();
                fieldInfo.SetValue(this, null);
            }
        }
    }
}


class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    private MyDisposable _disposableC = new MyDisposable("_disposableC");
    private MyDisposable _disposableD = new MyDisposable("_disposableD");

    public MyDisposable DisposableC
    {
        get { return _disposableC; }
    }

    public MyDisposable DisposableD
    {
        get { return _disposableD; }
    }
}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(MyBaseClass instance = new MyClass())
        {
           Console.WriteLine(instance.BaseProtectedDisposableA.Name + " is telling his name...");
           Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

And it prints something like this:

```
_baseProtectedDisposableA is telling his name...
-------------------------------------------------------
_disposableC is disposed
_disposableD is disposed
_baseProtectedDisposableA is disposed
```

The question is how to make it print this one:

```
_baseProtectedDisposableA is telling his name...
-------------------------------------------------------
_disposableC is disposed
_disposableD is disposed
_baseProtectedDisposableA is disposed
_baseDisposableB is disposed
```

Or, in other words, where is my private field _baseDisposableB, and how to make it be disposed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get private fields of a base type by using `GetType().GetFields(...)`. You have to get the fields from the base type itself.

**Example**: Replace your `Dispose` method with these two methods:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    var type = GetType();
    while (type != null)
    {
        DisposeFields(type);
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
}

private void DisposeFields(Type type)
{
    var fieldInfos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
    {
        var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(this) as IDisposable;
        if (value == null) continue;

        value.Dispose();
        fieldInfo.SetValue(this, null);
    }
}
```

This will go through the inheritance hierarchy and `Dispose` the base type's fields (if they're disposable).

Result:

```
_baseProtectedDisposableA is telling his name...
--------------------------------------------------------
_disposableC is disposed
_disposableD is disposed
_baseProtectedDisposableA is disposed
_baseDisposableB is disposed
```

Answer (score 1):

> where is my private field _baseDisposableB

Read the docs on the [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) enumeration:

> **FlattenHierarchy**   Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy should be returned. Private static members in inherited classes are not returned. Static members include fields, methods, events, and properties. Nested types are not returned.

So private members from base classes are not returned.  Which makes sense, since private members are not *supposed* to be accessible from derived classes.

> how to make it be disposed?

Since accessing private members is a bit of a hack anyways, I would not try to dispose it from the derived class.  I would instead explicitly `Dispose` it in the base class directly:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    var fieldInfos = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

    foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
    {
        var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
        if (value is IDisposable)
        {
            ((IDisposable)value).Dispose();
            fieldInfo.SetValue(this, null);
        }
    }
    _baseDisposableB.Dispose();
}
```

Although I assume you have some reason for wanting to use reflection instead of explicitly disposing members anyways...